# Error initializing React Native app: "Your Ruby version is 2.6.10, but your Gemfile specified 2.7.5"

Tags: ruby, react-native, macos

I know similar questions exist.

I've gone through most of them but, so far, none of the solutions worked.

Here is the context:

Operating system: **macOS Ventura 13.0.1** (Intel processor)

Here are some commands output:

```
$ ruby -v
ruby 2.7.5p203 (2021-11-24 revision f69aeb8314) [x86_64-darwin22]
$ which ruby
/Users/..../.rbenv/shims/ruby
$  bundler -v
Bundler version 2.3.26
$ which bundler
/Users/..../.rbenv/shims/bundler
```

My **~/.bash_profile** and **~/.zshrc** contain:

```
export PATH="$HOME/.rbenv/bin:$PATH"
eval "$(rbenv init -)"
export PATH="$HOME/.rbenv/shims:$PATH"
eval "$(rbenv init -)"
```

I know nothing about **ruby**, I'm using `rbenv` to manage **ruby** versions.

I've done a similar setup on another macOS system but for some reason, on this system, nothing I have tried works.

Any helps is appreciated.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've managed to make it work.

I'm not sure what did it.

I've upgraded node from 14 to 19 which also upgraded react-native to 0.70.6

Also, I've added `if which rbenv > /dev/null; then eval "$(rbenv init -)"; fi` to **.bash_profile** and **.zshrc**

Answer (score 0):

In the directory where you run `npx react-native init`, try following code :

```
rbenv init
rbenv shell 2.7.5
eval "$(rbenv init - bash)";
```